# How to concatenate two arrays elements by elements accordingly?

Tags: ruby, arrays

E.g

```
a = [a,b,c]
b = [1,2,3]
```

I want:

```
[a1,b2,c3]
```

a, b are with the same length and are all string arrays.

Any native ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, for example

```
a = %w{a b c}
b = %w{1 2 3}

c = a.map.with_index do |elem, idx|
  elem + b[idx]
end

c # => ["a1", "b2", "c3"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
%w(a b c).zip(%w(1 2 3))
# => [["a","1"],["b","2"],["c","3]]
```

If you want to concatenate the strings:

```
%w(a b c).zip(%w(1 2 3)).map(&:join)
# => ["a1","b2","c3"]
```

This extends to more arrays:

```
%w(a b c).zip(%w(1 2 3), %w(x y z)).map(&:join)
# => ["a1x", "b2y", "c3z"]
```